# What are the changes between BLtouch 3.0 and 3.1?

Tags: bltouch

I couldn't find a reliable source listing the improvements of BLtouch 3.1 vs 3.0.

I can see that BLtouch 3.0 is sold (original) for about 20 Euro, while 3.1 costs about 30 Euro. The difference is significant.

What are the improvements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best reference would be the original equipment manufacturer (Antclabs). It appears their sensor has had many [versions](https://www.antclabs.com/version):

[image]

So, from 3.0 to 3.1 is a software upgrade. Reported highlights are:

> ★ Smart V3.0 (Mar. 2019 ~ ) : S10, S60, S90, S120, S140, S150, S160,
> PWM Wiring defect indication(Blue LED), QR, Molex 1.25, Plastic
> Push-pin(PC), Power Wiring defect indication(Red LED)
>
> ★ Smart V3.1 (Mar. 2019 ~ ) : S10, S60, S90, S120, S130, S140, S150,
> S160, PWM Wiring defect indication(Blue LED), QR, Molex 1.25, Plastic
> Push-pin(PC), Power Wiring defect indication(Red LED)

If you look at the manuals you will see the differences:

V3.0
[image]

V3.1
[image]

As can be seen, timings are different and more PWM position G-code options are available in the V3.1.